# Why does a generic cast of a List<? extends Set..> to List<Set..> succeed on Sun JDK 6 but fail to compile on Oracle JDK 7?

Tags: java, generics, java-7

The following code

```
class GenericCompilationFailureDemo {
    List<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo> newList() { 
        return new ArrayList<GenericCompilationFailureDemo>(); 
    };

    void useList() {
        List<GenericCompilationFailureDemo> list = 
            (List<GenericCompilationFailureDemo>) newList();
    }  

    List<? extends Set<GenericCompilationFailureDemo>> newListOfSpecificSets() { 
        return new ArrayList<Set<GenericCompilationFailureDemo>>(); 
    };

    void useListOfSpecificSets() {
        List<Set<GenericCompilationFailureDemo>> listOfSpecificSets = 
            (List<Set<GenericCompilationFailureDemo>>) newListOfSpecificSets();
    } 

    List<? extends Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>> newListOfSets() { 
        return new ArrayList<Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>>(); 
    };

    void useListOfSet() {
        List<Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>> listOfSets = 
            (List<Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>>) newListOfSets();
    }  
}
```

compiles under Sun JDK 1.6.0_20 (64-bit on Windows Vista, but I don't think that makes any difference) but causes the following compilation failure under Oracle JDK 1.7.0_01 (same platform):

```
[ERROR] src\main\java\GenericCompilationFailureDemo.java:[56,78] error: inconvertible types
```

Note that the first *two* "extends-to-specific-type" casts in `useList` and `useListOfSpecificSets` both still succeed under 1.7.0_01, so it would seem it's something to do with the "double generic extends".

Any ideas what might have changed between 6 and 7, and whether the observed behaviour is according to spec or a bug?

*edited in response to Sanjay's comment:*

@Sanjay: Aha, interesting! Here the output from `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

And here the result of `javac GenericCompilationFailureDemo.java` (same code as above with import statements for List, ArrayList and Set):

```
GenericCompilationFailureDemo.java:30: error: inconvertible types
            (List<Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>>) newListOfSets()
;
                                                                              ^
  required: List<Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>>
  found:    List<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo> from capture of ?
 extends Set<? extends GenericCompilationFailureDemo>
Note: GenericCompilationFailureDemo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this code compiles on my JDK 7. Can you post the entire output of `java -version` command along with the "build" string?

Comment: please paste the exact compile errors  + what sanjay has suggested.  *I believe the generics are supposed to be somewhat simpler in java 7* in some cases... maybe you found a corner case where older, complex, JDK 6 syntax  breaks the new compiler  .

Comment: @Sanjay: aha, interesting! See the edited question for responses to your comments

Comment: javac seem to have a bad habit of spontaneously rejecting generic casts that are legal per JLS, see [bug 6790039](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6790039) and especially the _looooong_ list of _Related Bugs_ mentioned there (16 as of now) - yours might be there in this list :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is apparently a javac7 bug. It should be allowed per casting conversion rules [1]

One of the rules allows *a narrowing reference conversion ... followed by an unchecked conversion*

Casting `List<A> => List<B>` is allowed by this rule

```
List<A> => List   // narrowing reference conversion
List => List<B>   // unchecked conversion
```

That's not all the story though; the spec has further rules to forbid casting like `List<String>=>List<Integer>`, for they are *provably distinct parameterized
types*. There is no object belonging to the two types at the same time, so compiler think it's better to disallow this apparent programming error. (You can bypass it by explicitly `List<String>=>List=>List<Integer>`)

The last rule doesn't apply here though; so it looks like a javac7 bug.

Why the last rule doesn't apply: so we are casting `List<? extends A>` to `List<A>`. Here capture conversion is applied to `List<? extends A>` [2] so we are actually casting `List<T>` to `List<A>`, where `T` is a new type variable with upper bound `A`.

The question is whether `List<T>` and `List<A>` are *provably distinct parameterized types*. My understanding is that it's false (it has to be false for your first two examples to compile). Since `T` is a type variable, it can take a value to make `List<T>` and `List<A>` the same parameterized type (i.e. when `T=A`). This reasoning should work for any type `A`.

[1] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5

[2] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341306

Comment: _You can bypass it by explicitly List<String>=>List=>List<Integer>)_

I verified that, indeed - but "hacking generics" was not something I really wanted to commit ;-)

Thanks for the explanation! Is there anyone within Oracle you'd suggest to contact (e.g. the compiler-dev list or so?) to see whether it's worth filing a bug for this?

Comment: Just posted to compiler-dev. Curious to see what kind of responses we'll get ;-)

Comment: @AndrewPhillips Hey can u tell us about that response :) I'm curious to see that hacking free solution.