# Type inference more restrictive in JDK 7 than JDK 6?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, java-7

I think this might be related to [Why does a generic cast of a List<? extends Set..> to List<Set..> succeed on Sun JDK 6 but fail to compile on Oracle JDK 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637937/why-does-a-generic-cast-of-a-list-extends-set-to-listset-succeed-on-sun)

If we take the following classes, they compile fine under JDK 6:

```
public final class Foo<V> {

    private final V value;

    private Foo(final V value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <T, R extends T> Foo<T> of(final R value) {

        return new Foo<T>(value);
    }
}

final class Tester {

    @Test(groups="unit")

    public static void test() {

        bar(Foo.of(BigDecimal.ZERO));  // This line fails in JDK 7 but not JDK 6
    }

    private static void bar(final Foo<? extends Number> target) {

        assert target != null;
    }
}
```

However, under JDK 7, I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] \work\fsb-core\src\test\java\com\fsb\core\Foo.java:[42,8] error:
              method bar in class Tester cannot be applied to given types;
```

I thought type inference was less restrictive (e.g., adding constructor inference) in JDK 7.  However, here, the compiler is rejecting a type that is valid under JDK 6.

Is this a bug?  Or were the rules on inference made more stringent for methods?

Comment: Java 8 (1.8.0_25) this compiles just fine again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly according to the spec, `T` cannot be inferred (per 15.12.2.7), so it should be taken as `Object`.

This can be viewed as a failure of the spec. This is how spec infers `R`: first there is constraint `R :> BigDecimal`, where `:>` means *is a supertype of*. The inference rules then choose `R=BigDecimal` since it's the most specific type satisfying the constraint.

Now, since `T:>R`, `T:>BigDecimal`, one would think this should yield `T=BigDecimal` too.

Unfortunately the inference rules do not take `T:>R` into account. There is no contraint on `T`. `T` is not inferred through the same principle.

While it sucks, spec is spec. Your code should not compile. Javac6 is wrong there.

In Java 8 there's an great improvement on inference rules to make lambda expression easier to use. Hopefully your code should compile in Java 8.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I am relieved that the type inference is correct in JDK 7 (tho somewhat disheartened it only worked accidentally in JDK 6).   It seems this is related to:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html.  (Referenced originally at http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6638712).