# Known Tomcat 6.0 and JDK 1.7.0_02 issues?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, java-7

Are there known `Tomcat 6.0` and `JDK 1.7.0_02` issues?

I know this is a hard question to answer, if the answer is no. But I need to ask just in case the answer is yes. Also I will accept any solutions to the issues below as answers. Please just share whatever issues you have had, and I will update this question if need be.

## Issues:

Some issues I have run into since upgrading from JDK 1.7.0 to 1.7.0_02 (*which I did to avoid the Eclipse's help menus from crashing, due to a Java 1.7.0 bug.*):

- Tomcat server takes much longer to start, I need a 120 second timeout to handle it.
- `FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)` error, which disappeared the next day and then reappeared the third day, with no changes other than reloading Eclipse.
- Tomcat server takes much longer to shut down. I need a 60 second timeout to handle it, from 15 second default.
- Eclipse itself appears to crawl to a halt (figuratively speaking) upon building the workspace and validating the project at hand. Everything within Eclipse appears to take longer, even opening an unopened file.

Everything seems suspicious.

P.S. `JDK 1.7.0_02` is also known as `1.7.0u2`, `Java SE 7u2`, `Java SE 7 Update 2`, etc.

## Versions:

- JDK = `Oracle`, 64-bit, downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. Exact file downloaded and installed was `jdk-7u2-windows-x64.exe`.
- Tomcat = `Tomcat 6.0.33`, downloaded separately from Eclipse
- Eclipse = `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.`, `Version: Indigo Release`, `Eclipse Platform`, `Version: 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f`, `Build id: I20110613-1736`.
- 64-bit Windows 7 machine, 8GB RAM, Intel Core i7-2600 CPU @ 3.4GHz (4 cores)
- Eclipse, Tomcat, Apache HTTP Server, are all on the same (development) computer.

EDIT: Added system specs above.

Comment: Which JDK - Oracle/SUN or OpebJDK?

Comment: @home, Orcale. I will edit my question and include this.

Comment: Are you using Tomcat from a separate install or from inside Eclipse? Which version of Tomcat (exactly) and Eclipse are you using? I guess it's the 32 bit version, right?

Comment: I am using `Tomcat 6.0.33`, downloaded separately from Eclipse, and `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.`, `Version: Indigo Release`, `Eclipse Platform`, `Version: 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f`, `Build id: I20110613-1736`. 64-bit machine. How can I double check my java version is also 64-bit? I have no idea if a 32-bit version would run or not, but if it did perhaps it would run slower? I will also add this to the question.

Comment: Verified I installed 64-bit version of JDK. The exact file is `jdk-7u2-windows-x64.exe`.

Comment: Matt, be sure to ask this on the Tomcat list.

Comment: @RiyadKalla, what and where is the Tomcat list? Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewDoucette Sorry about that, I meant the Tomcat-Users mailing list here: http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users -- you will need to subscribe to join, but then you can post your question there and it is targeted at the entire Tomcat user community. So if there is a bug, someone there is likely hit it and can help confirm or deny for you.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette Regarding your Eclipse slowdown, what is the value of the `-vm` option in your eclipse.ini file (in the root directory of your Eclipse installation)?  Also, if you open a command prompt and type `java -version`, what is the output?

Answer (score 1):

When running 64 bits Java with default options (references compaction is off by default), it requires almost twice the amount of memory than with 32 bits.

For Eclipse, open the `eclipse.ini` file and double/increase a lot the `-Xmx` option.

Of course, your physical memory may not be enough when running some JVMs.

So I recommend you to test the `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` [HotSpot option](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) with 64 bits JVM and monitor memory usage thanks to `jconsole` for instance. You can also read [details about that recent option](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops). That option

For Tomcat, create the file `bin/setenv.bat` with content:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Four things: 1) Right now (and back when I posted this question) I am running `-Xmx2048m` in `eclipse.ini` which I think is four times the size of default settings. 2) I have no `bin/setenv.bat` in my Tomcat folder, and nothing that looks close to it. Maybe explain this one more to me. 3) I have 8 GB RAM. 4) where do I set `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`? Thanks again so much!

Comment: Compressed oops is supported and enabled by default in Java SE 6u23 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps it's all about the new JVM released in that [update](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u2-relnotes-1394228.html). It alledgedly improves performance but... well, who knows. JDT on Tomcat6 interacts with JDK 1.7 so unexpected things could happen.
Other than that, there're [few things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660316/type-inference-more-restrictive-in-jdk-7-than-jdk-6) to check.