# Debugging remote container with arquillian fails

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

Debugging remote container jboss7.1.1 fails with arquillian. I set the debugging conf in the standalone.conf.bat as described here https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhyDontBreakPointsWorkWhenDebugging. But that doesn't starts the jboss in debugging mode.
Consoleoutput:

```
INFO: Starting container with: [D:\java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java, -Xmx512m,
 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m, -ea, -Djboss.home.dir=target/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final,
...
```

Using arquillian 1.0.3.Final.

Comment: Are you using standalone.bat to start the server? If not, the settings in standalone.conf.bat would not be applied. Running standalone.bat should print out the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable to the console (unlike your snippet).

Comment: Arquillian, which is a test-framework for enterprise applications, starts the server. I have no influence. I did it as described in this tutorial: http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/?utm_source=cta

Comment: So you're using a managed container? If so, see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/JBoss+AS+7.1%2C+JBoss+EAP+6.0+-+Managed) for the 7.1.x managed container config reference. You need to set the `javaVmArguments` in arquillian.xml

Comment: Thanks. That has helped. If you write it as answer I can accept it if you like.

Comment: Is there a definitive simple answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a managed container and arquillian is starting JBoss AS for you, you need to add the option to arquillian.xml. Something like:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
        <protocol type="jmx-as7">
            <property name="executionType">REMOTE</property>
        </protocol>
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">${basedir}/target/jboss-as-${jbossas.version}</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=y -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

Comment: I get: FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

Comment: Does any of this apply to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130184/fatal-error-in-native-method-jdwp-no-transports-initialized-jvmtierror-agent-e ?

Comment: I think not... running Jboss AS 7.1