# Unable to use the debugger ( Cannot connect to VM )

Tags: java, eclipse, window

I've Eclipse for quite a while, but I recently just came across an error that is really bugging me right now because I can't use the debugger. I can run my program normally, but not the debugger. This is what I get when I try to run with the debugger:

> 'Launching CarLoanUser' has encountered a problem
>   Cannot connect to VM
>   Cannot connect to VM
>   com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException

and in the console:

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized,
>   jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197) ERROR: transport error 202:
>   connect failed: Permission denied ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket
>   failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510) JDWP exit error
>   AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized
>   [debugInit.c:750]

I've tried a lot of things concerning it:

- restart Eclipse
- restart my computer
- Try another code I own
- Reinstall Eclipse (Luna)
- Delete Eclipse (Luna) and replace it with Eclipse Java EE (Kepler)
- Go back on Eclipse (Luna)
- Uninstall all instances of Java and install Java 8
- Uninstall Java 8 and install Java 7 (All Java installation are with the 64-bit installator)
- Clean the registery with ccleaner

I'm currently running on Windows 8.1 64-bit

If it might help, I'll include the code I'm currently working on

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * Title:  CarLoanUser
 * Description: 
 * @author 
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class CarLoanUser {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    runWithConsole();
}//main(args)

public static void runWithConsole()
{
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    CarLoanMethods user;
    int numberOfPayments = 0;
    double remainingAmount, remainingAmountInCalculation; 
    user = new CarLoanMethods();

    System.out.print("What is the model? ");
    user.setModel(key.nextLine());

    System.out.print("What is the loan amount? ");
    user.setLoanAmount(key.nextInt());
    remainingAmountInCalculation = user.getLoanAmount(); 

    System.out.print("What is the interest rate? ");
    user.setInterestRate(key.nextInt());

    System.out.print("What is the monthly payment? ");
    user.setMonthlyPayment(key.nextInt());

    user.calculateEverything();

    System.out.printf("\n%10s%35s", "Car model: ", user.getModel());
    System.out.printf("\n%14s%31s", "Amount to pay: ", money.format(user.getTotalPrice()));
    System.out.printf("\n%33s%12s", "Total interest that will be paid: ", money.format(user.getTotalInterest()));
    System.out.printf("\n%19s%26s", "Number of payments: ", user.getNumberOfPayments());

}//runWithConsole()
}//CarLoanUser class
```

And the method class:

```
/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class CarLoanMethods {

private String model;
private int loanAmount;
private int interestRate;
private int numberOfPayments = 0;
private double monthlyPayment;
private double interestTotal;
private double interest;
private double toBePaid;

public CarLoanMethods()
{
    model = "Unknown";
    loanAmount = 0;
    interestRate = 0;
    monthlyPayment = 0;
}//CarLoanMethods()

public CarLoanMethods(String userModel, int userLoan)
{
    model = userModel;
    loanAmount = userLoan;
    interestRate = 0;
    monthlyPayment = 0;
}//CarLoanMethods(String, int)

public CarLoanMethods(int userInternetRate, int userMonthlyPayment)
{
    model = "Unknown";
    loanAmount = 0;
    interestRate = userInternetRate;
    monthlyPayment = userMonthlyPayment;
}//CarLoanMethods(int, int)

public void setModel(String userModel)
{
    model = userModel;
}//setModel(String)
public String getModel()
{
    return model;
}//getModel()

public void setLoanAmount(int userLoan)
{
    loanAmount = userLoan;
}//setLoanAmount(int)
public int getLoanAmount()
{
    return loanAmount;
}//getLoanAmount()

public void setInterestRate(int userInterestRate)
{
    interestRate = userInterestRate;
}//setInterestRate(int)
public int getInterestRate()
{
    return interestRate;
}//getInterestRate()

public void setMonthlyPayment(double userMonthlyPayment)
{
    monthlyPayment = userMonthlyPayment;
}//setMonthlyPayment(double)
public double getMonthlyPayment()
{
    return monthlyPayment;
}//getMonthlyPayment()


public double getTotalInterest()
{
    return interestTotal;
}//getTotalInterest()

public double getTotalPrice()
{
    return interestTotal + loanAmount;
}//getTotalPrice

public int getNumberOfPayments()
{
    return numberOfPayments;
}

public void calculateEverything()
{
    double remainingAmountInCalculation = getMonthlyPayment();
    while (remainingAmountInCalculation >= 0)
    {   

        interest = remainingAmountInCalculation * ((interestRate / 100.0) / 12.0);
        interest = Math.round(interest * 100.0) / 100.0;
        remainingAmountInCalculation =  (remainingAmountInCalculation + interest) - monthlyPayment;
        interestTotal += interest;
        ++numberOfPayments;
    }
}
}//CarLoanMethods
```

The program should work as I intended it to do. I know it need some work, but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this issue for a while.
I couldn't really find a definitive solution (one that makes it work 100% of the time) but at least I can debug.

First you need to check if javaw is already using the port. To do that in Windows you have two options:

- go to the task manager -> resource monitor -> network.

And there check for listening ports (javaw uses 5001 and 8080)

- run -> cmd -> and then type: netstat -n

You'll see the ports 5001 and 8080 on listening.

If you see the ports opened is not going to debug. Run the application as normal, stop it, wait a few seconds and check again.

If you don't see them on listening then you can debug, but don't do it through the menus; go to Run -> Debug configurations -> and press debug from there.

I know is not a definitive solution (and this problem is already 1 year old) but that worked for me enough to let me debug and continue developing.

Comment: Note: I already checked a few times if the firewall was blocking it or not. I definitely need to check the resource monitor and wait for the javaw instances to die before I can debug. For some reason compiling kills the current processes whilst debugging does not.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130184/fatal-error-in-native-method-jdwp-no-transports-initialized-jvmtierror-agent-e) solution says it could be because the port the debugger wants to use it being taken.

I think it could also be a firewall blocking it, make sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These two things helped me...

1. clean temp file with %temp%
2. Remove all breakpoints from application

then run the application again!