# Tomcat server not working when deployed on remote machine

Tags: java, tomcat, ssh, server

I have installed Tomcat server on remote machine from ssh/Terminal. But it does not work, i did the below steps:

1. 'wget' the tar from net
2. tar -xvf "tar file name"
3. change the Http port from 8080(already used) to 8083
4. change the ajp port from 8009 (alreday used) to 8089
5. added the username, role, pwd in tomcat.users.xml
6. After changes restarted the tomcat server

Not sure if any other setting is required to be changed

I tried the 'remote host ip:8083' but no page opens, in catalina.out log no error is seen

Server.xml:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!--
      Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license .......
    -->
    <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
     -->
    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
      <Listener         className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
      <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
      <Listener  className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener"     />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"     secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8089" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web     applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using     pattern="common"     -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

          </Host>
        </Engine>
      </Service>
        </Server>
```

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130184/fatal-error-in-native-method-jdwp-no-transports-initialized-jvmtierror-agent-e/9198355#9198355)

Comment: tx, not wrking still but trying

Comment: Post your server.xml

Comment: Is your firewall configured properly, e.g. is 8083 externally accessible?

Comment: @shinjw... here is the server.xml

Comment: @Stugal .....how do set 8083 to be externally accessible

Comment: @Stugal ... i think port 8083 is open ..i tried as below:

Comment: [root@ bin]# netstat -an | grep 8083 | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 :::8083                     :::*                        LISTEN      
[root@ bin]# netstat -an | grep 8089 | grep -i listen
[root@ bin]#

Comment: @Stugal ..... do the port 8089 used for ajp need sto be open as well ....i am not sure

Comment: i don't think that nestat checks if the port is externally accessible, try pinging the remote machine from your local machine e.g. ping xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu:8083

Comment: Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" to 8083